# Ansible: Merge 2 lists using common key

Tags: ansible

I have a use case where I need to merge 2 lists on common key name using Ansible.

List1:

```
 {
        "poc-cu2": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:22"
        ],
        "test2211": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:22"
        ],
        "test2244": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:45",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:46"
        ]
    }
```

List2:

```
{
        "poc-cu2": [
            "root",
            "9WKA3KK3XN39",
            "9.3.13.44"
        ],
        "test2211": [
            "root2211",
            "221122112211",
            "9.3.13.82"
        ]
    }
```

Expected:

List3:

```
{
        "poc-cu2": [
            "root",
            "9WKA3KK3XN39",
            "9.3.13.44",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:22"
        ],
        "test2211": [
            "root2211",
            "221122112211",
            "9.3.13.82",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:22"
        ]
    }
```

I got how to merge 2 lists using unique key but on my case I need to merge only on common key, please suggest.

Comment: Those aren't lists, those are dictionaries. Also, why isn't `test2244` in the final list? Are you explicitly excluded keys that aren't in both lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get most of what you want using the [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        dict3: "{{ dict1|combine(dict2, list_merge='append') }}"

    - debug:
        var: dict3
```

This will produce:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict3": {
        "poc-cu2": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:22",
            "root",
            "9WKA3KK3XN39",
            "9.3.13.44"
        ],
        "test2211": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:22",
            "root2211",
            "221122112211",
            "9.3.13.82"
        ],
        "test2244": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:45",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:46"
        ]
    }
}
```

If you want the final result to consist of only the keys common to both
dictionaries it gets a little trickier, but this seems to work:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        dict3: "{{ dict3|combine({item: dict1[item] + dict2[item]}) }}"
      when: item in dict2
      loop: "{{ dict1.keys() }}"
      vars:
        dict3: {}

    - debug:
        var: dict3
```

Which produces:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict3": {
        "poc-cu2": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:22:22",
            "root",
            "9WKA3KK3XN39",
            "9.3.13.44"
        ],
        "test2211": [
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:11",
            "40:A6:B7:5E:33:22",
            "root2211",
            "221122112211",
            "9.3.13.82"
        ]
    }
}
```

The above works by iterating over the keys in `dict1`, and for each
key from `dict1` that also exists in `dict2`, we synthesize a new
dictionary containing the corresponding values from both `dict1` and `dict2` and then merge it into our final dictionary using the `combine` filter.

Answer (score 0):

Given the data

```yaml
    dict1:
      poc-cu2:
        - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:11
        - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:22
      test2211:
        - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:11
        - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:22
      test2244:
        - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:45
        - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:46

    dict2:
      poc-cu2:
        - root
        - 9WKA3KK3XN39
        - 9.3.13.44
      test2211:
        - root2211
        - '221122112211'
        - 9.3.13.82
```

---

Iteration is not needed. Put the declarations below as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). The dictionary *dict_cmn* keeps the merged common attributes of *dict1* and *dict2*

```yaml
dict_1_2: "{{ dict1|combine(dict2, list_merge='append') }}"
keys_cmn: "{{ dict1.keys()|intersect(dict2.keys()) }}"
vals_cmn: "{{ keys_cmn|map('extract', dict_1_2) }}"
dict_cmn: "{{ dict(keys_cmn|zip(vals_cmn)) }}"
```

give

```yaml
  dict_1_2:
    poc-cu2:
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:11
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:22
    - root
    - 9WKA3KK3XN39
    - 9.3.13.44
    test2211:
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:11
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:22
    - root2211
    - '221122112211'
    - 9.3.13.82
    test2244:
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:45
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:46

  keys_cmn:
  - poc-cu2
  - test2211

  vals_cmn:
  - - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:11
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:22
    - root
    - 9WKA3KK3XN39
    - 9.3.13.44
  - - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:11
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:22
    - root2211
    - '221122112211'
    - 9.3.13.82

  dict_cmn:
    poc-cu2:
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:11
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:22:22
    - root
    - 9WKA3KK3XN39
    - 9.3.13.44
    test2211:
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:11
    - 40:A6:B7:5E:33:22
    - root2211
    - '221122112211'
    - 9.3.13.82
```